# Why does Stack Exchange run a school for smoke detectors?

Tags: discussion, chat, smokedetector

I just noticed that Stack Exchange runs a [school for smoke detectors](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17251/smoke-detector-school). I'm not complaining, I'm just wondering why we have one. I'm asking here because it doesn't seem to be associated with a specific site.

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17251/smoke-detector-school

Comment: Anyone can create a chat room, don't take chat room titles as anything reflecting Stack-Exchange-the-company.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That room isn't run by Stack Exchange (well, it sorta is as they host it, but you get what I mean :P). It's owned by [The Charcoal Team](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE) who runs a bot, SmokeDetector, that aims to detect spam on the network and posts it in chat rooms. The "Smoke Detector School" room exists for testing and running Beta features.

Comment: So that is who SmokeDetector is.

Comment: So the bot there doesn't respond to commands? :(

Comment: Can it actually detect smoke? I'm just joking. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, it doesn't.

Comment: @PythonMaster: the spam detector bot is called Smoke Detector. Coz. it raises an alarm if it smells something spammy.

Comment: @Mart is right, when we'll have bot that can nuke spammers, it would be called Fire Extinguisher. ;)

Comment: So I could create a chat room for those who didn't make chat rooms for themselves then.

Comment: Can I write a module for SmokeDetector that wires it to my house's fire alarm system? Please? I'm totally willing to do this.

Comment: @PyRulez Yes, you could -- but in most cases you don't need to, unless the people who need it don't have enough rep, or it's a room for a chatbot.

Comment: @Emrakul Be warned for continuous alerts! *evil grin*

Comment: @ProgramFOX It was a set theory joke. Look up set theory barber.

Comment: @PyRulez You mean [this paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barber_paradox)? Interesting one!

Comment: The back end service publishes a websocket of events so it would not be super hard to route those to your home automation. The joke gets old pretty quickly, though; you'd get around 100 alerts per day at the current spam levels (much more when Ryan is trawling old posts and reporting any we missed).