# Smoke detector bad keyword detection

Tags: discussion, chat, offensive, robots

Recently, the smoke detector has identified [a Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3110711/1) as a post [containing bad keywords](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49018342#49018342).  As a 10k user on Math.SE, I *can't* see any spam in this post.

What has triggered the alarm?  What does the number "97" mean in the generated message?

Comment: SmokeDetector is a community run project to help to fight spam. Therefore your question is unfortunately off-topic for this site. You can find help in [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) chatroom. To answer your specific question: The 97 is a sum of the probability of all reasons that apply to the post. A post is shown in the chatroom if it is on your site, the chat owners want this and it has at least one reason matching it. Also the appearance in the chatroom does nothing to the post. Only when SD is certain that a post is spam, it can be autoflagged by other users

Comment: @MEEisJohannGambolputty... Sorry, I didn't know this due to [existing questions about SmokeDetector](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=SmokeDetector).  I've flagged my question as off-topic.

Comment: The MS link in that chat message you linked to answers your question: https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/159335 just don't try to *lose weight* on the SE network ...

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 as others have noted, asking in Charcoal HQ is better, but in this specific case, the keyword filter caught "lose weight" within the question body, as that is a turn of phrase commonly used in pharma supplement spam. Ref: https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/159335

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 They are mostly questions that also relate to the software that powers the Stack Exchange network (aka Can we combine SD and SE) or are asking for permission to extend SDs tools. Here are more information on where you can ask: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272516/what-is-the-right-place-to-ask-questions-about-the-smokedetector

Comment: @rene Magisch MEE Thx all for links.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SmokeDetector is a community-run project, and not run by Stack Exchange. Issues should be reported at the [Charcoal HQ chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540) or on [GitHub](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector). If you have access, you can also ask on the [Stack Overflow Team](https://stackoverflow.com/c/charcoal).

Comment: Just a quick glance: Contains bad keyword `!=` it is spam. Though it's usually true, it isn't *strictly* true.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One way to quickly see the reason for the report is clicking the "MS" link: (metasmoke)

> [image]

In your case it leads to [this page](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/159335) where you can see this:

> Reason weight: 97
>
> Bad keyword in body - Position 123-134: lose weight

Now as you can easily imagine, "lose weight" is used many times by spammers, hence the bot was taught to detect and report any post containing it.

You can also see that someone already marked that report as false positive:

> [image]